# What ESP32 pins to connect to the NAU8810 audio codec?

Tags: esp32, audio-codec

[image]

What ESP32 pins to connect to an [NAU8810](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Nuvoton%20PDFs/NAU8810_Datasheet_Rev_2.8.pdf#page=98) audio codec? Or rather the other way around. I need an RX pin. Would this be tied to DACIN?

Pins I'm unsure about:

- MOUT (Mono Output)
- ADCOUT (Digital Audio Data Output)
- DACIN (Digital Audio Data Input)
- FS (Frame Sync)
- BCLK (Bit Clock)

What I have so far:

[image]

Typical application from the datasheet:

[image]

Or does the ESP32 clock not work with this IC?

Comment: Pins you need to connect would depend on your intended application. Also you need 2,2k pull-ups on SDIO and SCLK.

Comment: Application is just getting instrument sounds: https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/302

Answer (score 1):

Both your codec and ESP32 support either [PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) or [I2S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2S) interfaces. You should read about them and decide which one you want to use.

As for which pins to use on ESP32, ESP32 has a fully connected matrix, so you can choose any pin and simply assign a desired function to it in code.

Also check [ESP IDF documentation for I2S](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/i2s.html) for more information.